# creating basic button with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am making a button that changes from "you" > "wow" > "travel" with every click.

but it makes an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: onoff is not a function at HTMLInputElement.onclick (7.html:15)"

Can you help me solve this problem?

```js
function onoff() {
  currentvalue = document.getElementById('onoff').value;
  
  if (currentvalue == "you") {
    document.getElementById('onoff').value = "wow";
  } else if (currentvalue == "wow";) {
    document.getElementById('onoff').value = "travel";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('onoff').value = "you";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="you" id="onoff" onclick="onoff();">
```

Comment: `.value` doesn't capture the text element inside the button element. Use `innerText` instead.

Comment: @RonRoyston Better to use `.textContent`, only use `.innerText` if you really need it http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/ (but in this case, `.value` is just fine)

Comment: @CertainPerformance oh i see he's nailed down a `value` attribute on a `button` element. But yes, `.textContent` (vs `innerText`) is good call.  In any case, I'm not fan of using a value attribute on a `button` nor of programatically altering buttons as it violates the KISS principle. I'd just creates a button for each action and show/hide as needed.

Answer (score 3):

```js
function onoff() {
  var currentvalue = document.getElementById('onoff').value;
  if (currentvalue == "you") {
    document.getElementById('onoff').value = "wow";
  } else if (currentvalue == "wow") {
    document.getElementById('onoff').value = "travel";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('onoff').value = "you";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="you" id="onoff" onclick="onoff()">
```

Done, all is work :

i have been replace `onclick="onoff();"` and `else if (currentvalue == "wow";)`

the problems was only in syntax typo

Comment: Glad to hear if it helps you, please accept the answer

Comment: Typo questions should be flagged and closed, not answered

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript function wasn't declared because it has a typo in it.
Also I'd like to suggest to put the words you like to iterate through in an array, which makes the code easier to extend or modify. It also improves the readability.

```js
var words = ["you", "wow", "travel"];
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var index = 0;

button.value = words[index++];

function onoff() {
  button.value = words[index++ % words.length];
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button" onclick="onoff()" />
```